# Tkinter key bind don't work with key: "PrintScreen"

Tags: python, tkinter, key-bindings

im trying to build a "Key-Test" Programm which should show if a key works. (Im from the custom keyboard community)

My code is working fine for "esc" and "F1"-"F12" but with "PrintScreen" it dont work. I don't know why it works with all the other keys and not with printscreen.
here is the code snippet from the relevant passage:

```
from tkinter import *
window = Tk()
c = Canvas(window, width=1135, height=300, bg="lavender")
c.pack()

#Create the rectangle for PrintScreen, ScrollLock and Pause
key13 = c.create_rectangle(772.5, 10, 812.5, 50, fill="white") #PrintScreen
key14 = c.create_rectangle(822.5, 10, 862.5, 50, fill="white") #ScrollLock
key15 = c.create_rectangle(872.5, 10, 912.5, 50, fill="white")  # Pause

#(german) Text for each Key 
text13 = c.create_text(791, 20, text="Druck", font=('Helvetica', '8'))
text14 = c.create_text(841, 20, text="Rollen", font=('Helvetica', '8'))
text15 = c.create_text(891, 20, text="Pause", font=('Helvetica', '8'))

#event functions 
def key_event13(event):
    c.itemconfig(key13, fill="DarkSeaGreen2")


def key_event14(event):
    c.itemconfig(key14, fill="DarkSeaGreen2")


def key_event15(event):
    c.itemconfig(key15, fill="DarkSeaGreen2")


#bind the keys
c.bind_all("<KeyPress-Print>", key_event13)
c.bind_all("<KeyPress-Scroll_Lock>", key_event14)
c.bind_all("<KeyPress-Pause>", key_event15)

window.mainloop()
```

I already tried to use

```
c.bind_all("event.keysym_num == 65377", key_event13)
```

instead of

```
c.bind_all("<KeyPress-Print>", key_event13)
```

that doesn't work either...

I hope someone here can help me.
Best regards Simon

Comment: I suspect your operating system is handling that keypress itself, and not even passing it on to the application.

Comment: You can figure out if tkinter is reacting to that key. Do `root.bind("<Key>", lambda e: print(e.keysyms)` and press the print screen button.

Comment: I tried it with the follow tiny programm:
https://www.codespeedy.com/detect-keypress-in-tkinter-in-python/

tkinker don't recognize that "PrintScreen"-Key...
But its working, i tested it on a key-test website...

Answer (score 0):

I can't tell you why exactly it doesn't work, but you can solve this by using the [`keyboard`](https://pypi.org/project/keyboard/) module:

```
pip install keyboard
```

It has a function for listening to key presses and so you can use that to detect when print screen key is pressed and invoke a callback (so you would use this instead of `bind`):

```py
keyboard.on_press_key('print screen', key_event13)
```

So the complete version (without the unnecessary parts) would be:

```py
from tkinter import Tk, Canvas
import keyboard


def key_event13(event):
    # may want to add this since `keyboard` listens to all keyboard events and
    # so even if the window is not in focus it will call this function
    # which these two lines would prevent if needed
    if window.focus_get() is None:
        return
    c.itemconfig(key13, fill="DarkSeaGreen2")
    

window = Tk()

c = Canvas(window, width=1135, height=300, bg="lavender")
c.pack()

key13 = c.create_rectangle(772.5, 10, 812.5, 50, fill="white")
text13 = c.create_text(791, 20, text="Druck", font=('Helvetica', '8'))

keyboard.on_press_key('print screen', key_event13)

window.mainloop()
```

Obviously for the rest of the keys just use `bind`.

Also:
I strongly advise against using wildcard (`*`) when importing something, You should either import what You need, e.g. `from module import Class1, func_1, var_2` and so on or import the whole module: `import module` then You can also use an alias: `import module as md` or sth like that, the point is that don't import everything unless You actually know what You are doing; name clashes are the issue.

As a side note (my opinion) for organizing your code I would also suggest that you separate functions from the GUI as I have done in my example so that the code is more readable.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer and tips! Unfortunately, even this does not work. I have already written a programme that displays the pressed keys and my PrintScreen key is not recognised at all... Maybe I try it with another IDE (working with PyCharm) or with a new installation... Does your code example work for you?

Comment: yes it does work, you could try using the `keyboard` module's function that listens to keystrokes and you could press print screen and see what name it has if it is registered at all, also could try using some windows api but otherwise I don't know